# How to get all file name that stored in blob storage and saved it into table or csv

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I have trying to list all filename/url in my blob containter and save it to csv or table in azure sql database.

I was struggling in ADF with metadata activity:

[image]

But I can take the child item into table or csv. Is there any advice?

Comment: You could create a stored produce in the Azure SQL database. Then using get Metadata 
 active and Stored procedure. Set the Get Metadata output as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use logic app to achieve your needs, because it is very simple, the specific design is shown in the figure:

[image]

As the url is in this format:

```
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob
```

You need to define a variable as a prefix.

The usage of List blobs, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#list-blobs). For how to connect to your Azure database, you can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure#connect-to-your-database).

===========**update**==============

Regarding your question on how to create a csv file, the answer is updated as follows：

I designed my `logic app` like this

[image]

[image]

In these steps, on how to create a csv table, you can learn from this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#customize-table-format).

I tested it for you and found no problems：

[image]

Comment: This is awesome thanks, How about creating the blob list to a csv file? I have tried but it keep saving 1 file name

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the list in a C# program, you could use BlobContainerClient.GetBlobs()